# Calling C++ code from ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, starling-framework, ane

Here's the problem: I'm creating my new game which has some inapp items. I am using the Starling Framework for the game so I develop on AS3. I want to protect the game from genius(!) players who may attempt to break into inapp purchase process.

AS3 calls an in-app ANE (Milkman's), when a success returns from the ANE, my AS3 code sends an acknowledgement to my game server. So a malicious player can always send this acknowledgement info to my server without completing the in-app purchase process as if it was completed successfully.

So I thought of creating my own ANE which will also send this acknowledgement after it completes the process, so no AS3 code to mess with. I also don't want to use Java on Android to make things a little harder so I wonder if it's possible to call C++ code (which calls JNI for in-app purchases) from AS3.

Comment: I'd check Kongregate API on how do they do payment verification, and do alike. This is a pretty hard topic, how to protect from fake data submission.

Comment: Rule of thumb: rolling your own security solution is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milkman ANE is fine to use, google play has a proper secure way to protect your purchases from hacking - check out [billing-security](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-security) for GooglePlay. 
iTunes also has similar solution.

The main idea is to verify a purchase on server side with a private key which is only available for provider store (google play or iTunes) and your backend.